# Any diffrence in Ajax call & Web service API call

Tags: ajax, web-services, soap

What is the main difference Ajax call and web service APi call? Both are used for Link an api call. But one is Ajax and Other is Web Service API (REST & SOAP are protocols). Little bit confuse about the difference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX basically refers to making asynchronous request in JavaScript, traditionally sending/receiving . So that's the technique you use on client-side.

API and Web service serve as a means of communication. The only difference is that a Web service facilitates interaction between two machines over a network. An API acts as an interface between two different applications so that they can communicate with each other.